# How to retrieve the mimetype of a DbxEntry.File using the java Dropbox API

Tags: java, servlets, dropbox, dropbox-api

When I look at the API reference here:

http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.6.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.File.html

There's a "mimetype" field. Anyone know how to retrieve that from the object? I can't access it even though it's listed as being public there. I have version 1.7 of the java SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for 1.7 don't include that: http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxEntry.File.html

Comment: then how we get mimetype using 1.7 ?

Comment: You basically can't. The mimetype is not particularly useful, anyway. It's just a lookup based on the file extension, which you can just do yourself.

Comment: Thank for the comment..I am showing icon based on mimetype.

Comment: Right. You should switch to showing icons based on the file extension. (That would amount to the same thing.)